# python 2.7 - no module named tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i am on mac os x 10.8, using the integrated python 2.7.
i try to learn about tkinter with tutorials like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh6AdDX7K7U) for python 2.7 (explicitly not 3)
they propose the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
```

however, this brings up the error:

```
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

using import.Tkinter with a capital t seems to work, but further commands like

```
import Tkinter.messagebox
```

don't (neither does tkinter.messagebox).
I've had this problem with lots of tutorials. what's the thing with the capital / non-capital "T", and how do i get my python to work like it does in the tutorials? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the second case is it `No module named Tkinter` or `No module named messagebox` ?

Comment: the error goes like:      
import Tkinter.messagebox
ImportError: No module named messagebox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Tkinter (uppercase) you do not have messagebox.
You can use `Tkinter.Message` or `import tkMessageBox`

This code is an example taken [from this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_messagebox.htm):

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

top = Tkinter.Tk()
def hello():
   tkMessageBox.showinfo("Say Hello", "Hello World")

B1 = Tkinter.Button(top, text = "Say Hello", command = hello)
B1.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Your example code refers to a python installation >= py3.0. In Python 3.x the old good [Tkinter has been renamed tkinter](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tkinter.html#module-Tkinter).

Answer (score 11):

`Tkinter` (capitalized) refers to versions <3.0.

`tkinter` (all lowecase) refers to versions ≥3.0.

Source: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

Answer (score 0):

For python 2.7 it is Tkinter, however in 3.3.5 it is tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

For python 2.7 use Cap Letters Tkinter  but for >3.0 use small letter tkinter